# Partitioning the drives on a new laptop (Ubuntu installed)

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, dell

I need to know how can I resize the partitions in Ubuntu because I installed GParted and when I click on the drive(resize/move), it doesn't show any free space and the drive hasn't been partitioned earlier it contains 900 GB of free space.
Please help thanks!!!

Comment: Perhaps add a screenshot of gparted?  Also, have you selected the right drive?  See the dropdown box, in the top right of the gparted screen?

Answer (score 0):

Gparted cannot resize partitions if they are used. Try to boot your computer from a flash drive with ubuntu on it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your reply. My problem was solved. The main reason to partition the disk was to install windows. I booted up a windows 10 disk and opened cmd and used the diskpart command to convert gpt to ntfs and also partiton the drive, its all successfully done.